# Function that is discontinuous only for integer fractions

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I have this question:

> Find a function $f :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ which is discontinuous at the points of the
>   set $\{\frac1n : n \text{ a positive integer}\} \cup \{0\}$ but is continuous everywhere
>   else.

I really don't know what to do. I was thinking maybe:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 \quad&\text{if }x=0  \\
0 &\text{if } x \text{ is in } \{\tfrac1n : n \text{ a positive integer}\}\\     
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
But that kind of seems like 'cheating'. Is there a better example?

EDIT: Would it be better to have:

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x \text{ is in } \{\tfrac1n : n \text{ a positive integer}\}\cup \{0\}\\     
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Looks like Thomae's function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function

Comment: Actually a later part of this question seems to involve that function.

Comment: That's not cheating at all, as long as the function is well defined (it certainly is) and it verifies the requisites (does it?)

Comment: It does verify the requisites right? f(x) = 0 as x tends to 0 but f(0)=1 which is not the same, so it's discontinuous at 0, Same for all the 1/n as well, unless I've got this very wrong.

Comment: I fully agree with @leonbloy. Since the function satisfies the assumptions, it is a correct answer. It is good in that it is simple, so you immediately see what happens. That possibly makes it better than any "natural" example.

Comment: If you want to make more such functions, it is useful to note that $(1/n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence, so every subsequence must converge to $0$. So you can modify any continuous function on $[0,1]$ to have removable discontinuities on just the set $\{1/n\}\cup\{0\}$ and you'll have a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the fractional part function: $ \{x\} = \lceil x \rceil - x $, which is discontinuous at integers; to

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & ; x = 0 \\
\left\{\dfrac{1}{x}\right\} & ; otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume your **true** question is finding an answer that you do not consider "cheating."

**Question/Problem**
Find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is discontinuous at each point in $K\overset{\text{def}}{=}\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }n\ne 0\}\cup\{0\}$ and $f$ is continuous at each point in the complement of $K$ which is denoted $(\mathbb{R}\setminus K)$

**General Answer**
Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary continuous function.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be an arbitrary positive real number.

*Your edited answer has $g$ be the zero function and $\epsilon$ be $1$*

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
g(x)+\epsilon&\text{if }x\in K\\
g(x)&\text{if }x\in(\mathbb{R}\setminus K)
\end{cases}$$
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $K\overset{\text{def}}{=}\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }n\ne 0\}\cup\{0\}$.

The reason why I introduce "$K$" is because this method can be used for any given [**nowhere dense**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) set $K$ where you want discontinuities.
 <s>The set you were given is not special in any way for this problem. However it is a classic example of a compact set, but that's not relevant to your problem.</s>

Comment: Your reason for introducing $K$ is misleading. The given set *is* special: it contains no open intervals. If $K = [0, \infty)$ your construction yields a function with only one point of discontinuity: $0$.

Comment: Post has been edited. (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Put $A = \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n \geq 1\}$ and

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0 \quad x \notin A\cup \{0\} \\ 1 \quad x \in A \cup \{0\} \end{cases}$$